# Convert or filter members in CsvHelper when writing

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

Imagine I have a class like this

```
public class DataGroup 
{
    public string DataA { get; set; }
    public string DataB { get; set; }
    public bool Updated { get; set; }
}
```

I need to write an empty string or `"N/A"` for `DataA` and `DataB` when `Updated == false`, and the actual value when `Updated == true`;

Is this possible with CsvHelper?

Type conversion does not seem to work as it only access the final member so it is not able to read the value of `Updated`.

There is a `Conversion` method for the `MapMember` class but it seems to only work for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Convert` method.  This method can be a little confusing because it can either `ConvertFromString` or `ConvertToString`, depending on how you use it.

**ConvertFromString** *Use `Row` with `CsvReader`*

```cs
Map(m => m.DataA).Convert(m => m.Row.GetField("DataA") + m.Row.GetField("Updated"));
```

**ConvertToString** *Use `Value` with `CsvWriter`*

```cs
Map(m => m.DataA).Convert(m => m.Value.DataA + m.Value.Updated);
```

You want `ConvertToString`, so your `ClassMap` could be something like this.

```cs
public class DataGroupMap : ClassMap<DataGroup>
{
    public DataGroupMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.DataA).Convert(m =>
        {
            if (m.Value.Updated) { return m.Value.DataA; }
            return "N/A";
        });
        Map(m => m.DataB).Convert(m =>
        {
            if (m.Value.Updated) { return m.Value.DataB; }
            return "N/A";
        });
        Map(m => m.Updated);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks David. This certainly works and it is a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Updated == false)
{
    DataA = "N/A";
    DataB = "N/A";
}
else
{
     DataA = "Actual Information";
     DataB = "Actual Information";
}
```

Instead of "N/A" you can set the type to null

Comment: The idea is not having to modify the data class. So modifying the accessor is not an option